# ASP.NET POST receive issue

Tags: c#, post, model-view-controller

I have a following method in the Controller `Api`

```
[HttpPost]
public string TestMethod()
{
    var nvc = Request.Form;

    return Request.HttpMethod + " | " + string.Join("&", nvc.AllKeys.Select(a => a + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nvc[a])));
}
```

When I do the POST request from the browser, it works properly, but if I try to send the POST using C#, ASP returns 404 error
If I remove `[HttpPost]` before the method, ASP will tell that i am trying to make a GET request.

```
string url = "https://localhost:44300/Api/TestMethod";
        Dictionary<string, string> pars = new Dictionary<string, string>();
pars.Add("a", "b");
pars.Add("c", "d");
pars.Add("e", "f");
Console.WriteLine(POST(url, pars));
```

I've tried to manipulate with headers, but it was useless. Here's my POST method

```
static string POST(string url, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{

    HttpWebRequest hwr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
    hwr.KeepAlive = false;
    hwr.Method = "POST";
    hwr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    hwr.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0";

    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MakeQueryString(parameters));
    hwr.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (Stream reqStream = hwr.GetRequestStream())
    {
        reqStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    string result;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)hwr.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

UPD 1: I send POST request using RESTClient for Firefox; UPD 2: My C# method works for other websites

[RESTClient screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVWzf.png)

Comment: How are you doing POST request from the browser?

Comment: RESTClient for Firefox

Comment: Hi @ZelDa. Welcome to SO. You'll get better results if you post the full exception stack along with the code.

Comment: @JuanR he's getting a 404 not an exception.

So if the code works on other C# projects (and I cannot immediately see anything wrong with it) I would be looking at the project itself, can you please share a screenshot of what you are sending, the address etc. of RESTClient? I would be looking for any anomolies like the project isn't running in https or there is something different about the connection string that results.

Comment: @Slipoch Attached the screenshot. The ASP project is running on the localhost

Comment: @ZelDa: is it possible you have a filter or handler on your API that's rejecting your request and returning 404? Can you post the contents of `result`? I am curious to see what is returned. It may shed some light on what's causing this. I would also try removing the `UserAgent` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.
A problem was in `web.config`

```
<sessionState timeout="90" cookieless="AutoDetect" />
```

`AutoDetect` does the problem, to solve it, need to remove `cookieless="AutoDetect"`